# Syntax error: "(" unexpected in bash script

Tags: bash, syntax-error, sh

EDIT: I have fixed my script. It seems to be working. If anyone has any suggestions for improvement I would love the help. Apparently I needed to run it using bash instead of sh. 
Here is the updated script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /home/corey/box/*/*
do
dir=$(basename $"(dirname "$file")")
sudo chmod 0777 /var/log/torrentwatch.log
sudo chmod -R 0777 /home/corey/box/*/*
if [[ "$file" = /home/corey/box/*/*.torrent ]]
then
echo "[$(date)]" "$file added to queue." >> /var/log/torrentwatch.log
/usr/bin/transmission-remote localhost:9091 --auth=transmission:transmission -w /media/Media/Torrents/"$dir" -a "$file"
sleep 40 && rm "$file"
sleep 3 && sudo chmod -R 777 /media/Media && sudo chown -R debian-transmission:debian-transmission /media/Media/info
fi
done
```

The script is for adding torrent files to a folder and having them added to transmission. Here's the original version of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /home/me/box/*/*
do
dir=$(basename $(dirname "$file"));
sudo chmod 0777 /var/log/torrentwatch.log
sudo chmod -R 0777 /home/me/box/*/*
if "$file" = "/home/me/box/*/*.torrent"; then
echo [`date`] "$file" added to queue. >> /var/log/torrentwatch.log
/usr/bin/transmission-remote localhost:9091 --auth=transmission:transmission -l -w /media/Media/Torrents/$dir -a "$file"
sleep 40 && rm "$file"
sleep 3 && sudo chmod -R 777 /media/Media && sudo chown -R debian-transmission:debian-transmission /media/Media/info
fi
done
```

The problem is that when I run the script I get

```
/home/me/box/TV/Name.of.file.torrent: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I've tried running the script with bash, sh, and zsh, and none seem to work. I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Your if statement is wrong -- `if [[ $file = /home/me/box/*/*.torrent ]]` would work. Your echo needs more quotes -- `echo "[$(date)] $file added to queue"` would be safer. You need to quote your expansions -- anywhere you use `$dir` needs to be inside double-quotes.

Comment: Indenting your code would make it *much* easier to read.

Comment: Not a response to Keith, but `dir=$(basename $(dirname "$file"))` attempts to get the **filename** (`basename`) of the file after it has already been stripped by `dirname`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I think the idea is to get the base of the directory name, so for `/a/b/c/d.torrent` it would set `dir` to `c`.

Comment: Following up to my earlier comment, obviously `/home/me/box/TV/Name.of.file.torrent` has execute permission (though there's no good reason for it to), and the script is trying to execute it. Without a `#!` line, it's executed by `/bin/sh`, which produces that error message. Fixing the `if` condition will avoid executing the `*.torrent` files. (And doing a `chmod -x` on any files (not directories!) that don't need to be executable is a good idea.)

Comment: Oh, thank you Keith, I was scratching my head on that one..

Comment: @CharlesDuffy when I use your if statement with the brackets I get ./torrentwatch2.sh: [[: not found

Comment: @user450632, then you're running your script with `sh`, not `bash`. Since your shebang is correct (`#!/bin/bash`), I presume that you're explicitly starting it with `sh yourscript.sh`; don't do that. (It could also be that you have comments or other characters before your shebang; it needs to be at the very top of the file). `sh` doesn't have support for doing pattern matches built-in, which your code as currently formulated requires.

Comment: @user450632, ...by the way, `[[ ]]` isn't part of `if` syntax -- it's a separate command, and you can use it outside of `if` as well. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29

Comment: @user450632, ...try running `bash -x yourscript` to both (1) explicitly run it with bash, and (2) see what it's actually doing as it runs.

Answer (score 3):

This is the immediate problem:

```
if "$file" = "/home/me/box/*/*.torrent"
```

It's running the following:

```
/home/me/box/TV/Name.of.file.torrent = "/home/me/box/*/*.torrent"
```

...which is to say, it's trying to start the `.torrent` file as a script (with its first argument being `=` and its second argument being `/home/me/box/*/*.torrent`), which generates a syntax error. Instead, use:

```
if [[ $file = /home/me/box/*/*.torrent ]]
```

There are other issues elsewhere in this script -- I strongly recommend running it through http://shellcheck.net/.